# how to import curses in pycharm

Tags: pycharm, curses

I can't use `import curses` in my PyCharm. I dont know the problem. What should I do?

I already added `python -m pip install windows-curses` in my cmd. But my code that contain 'import curses' got error. It says that no module named curses.

```
import random
import curses


s = curses.initscr()
curses.curs_set(0)
sh, sw = s.getmaxyx()
w = curses.newwin(sh, sw, 0, 0)
w.keypad(1)
w.timeout(100)

snk_x = sw//4
snk_y = sh//2
```

this is the output error:

```
File "C:/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/snake/snake1", line 2, in <module>
        import curses

File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\curses\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
        from _curses import *
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_curses'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you didn't choose the correct python interpreter in PyCharm. 
You can quickly check which python interpreter you are using in PyCharm clicking on:

```
Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter
```

Here, in the top of the window, you should see the path and the name of project Interpreter that you are using. You can change using the drop-down select or if you need to add a new one, click on settings icon on the top-right corner of the window. Then click on Add and navigate to your virtualenv/python interpreter (remember that you have to choose the python file). 
Adding the interpreter, you should be able to use it, and so also your code should work well.

In case you are already using the correct interpreter, you should modify the configuration that you are using to run the program. In order to do this, simply click on:

```
Run -> Edit Configurations -> choose your configuration on the left
```

Here, on the right side of the window (Configuration tab) you should be able to choose the Python Interpreter. Then click on Apply and Ok.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install windows-curses package in Pycharm.

Check the attached photo:

[image: Installing Python libraries in Pycharm]

Comment: installing Python libraries into Pycharm

Answer (score 1):

I don't know so much about this module, but about that error I know it doesn't support windows environment and it isn't available on windows. For more information I attached report about this issue below, which I took from GitHub.

> The curses module is in the Python standard library, but is not
> available on Windows. Trying to import curses gives an import error
> for _curses, which is provided by Modules/_cursesmodule.c in the
> CPython source code. The wheels provided here are based on patches
> from https://bugs.python.org/issue2889, which make minor modifications
> to *cursesmodule.c to make it compatible with Windows and the PDCurses
> curses implementation. setup.py defines HAVE** macros for features
> available in PDCurses and makes some minor additional compatibility
> tweaks. The patched _cursesmodule.c is linked against PDCurses to
> produce a wheel that provides the _curses module on Windows and allows
> the standard curses module to run.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have a look at the question, and the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57255415/5698098) – and realize that _"that error I know it doesn't support windows environment and it isn't available on windows."_ is not the problem of this question, as such you're actually not answering the question. – As you start out here, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).